# Recording what people show me on my computer

Tags: screenshot, screen-capture, video-capture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free desktop recording / screencasting on windows](https://superuser.com/questions/201/free-desktop-recording-screencasting-on-windows)
>   [What is the best software for desktop recording?](https://superuser.com/questions/6801/what-is-the-best-software-for-desktop-recording)

Sometimes people come to show me stuff on my computer, and I would like tools to capture what they are showing me. I am mainly thinking of screenshots, but there are also videos of course.

I know many tools for screenshots, but it must be a tool for dumping a screen/window very quickly, wWithout specifying file-name, for example.

I have 4 monitors, one is usually a Debian VM, where I sometimes want to record commands
– it is a problem to seperate commands entered in different terminals.

Comment: and [Free desktop recording / screencasting on windows](http://superuser.com/questions/201/free-desktop-recording-screencasting-on-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to capture multi-step instructions, you might be better off with something like [RecordMyDesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php) for Ubuntu or [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) for windows. They make video recordings of what's going on on the desktop that you can play back later.